# Finding value in dict given an integer that can be found in between dictionary's tuple key

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, tuples, key-value

Given an `x` dictionary of tuple keys and string values:

```
x = {(0, 4): 'foo', (4,9): 'bar', (9,10): 'sheep'}
```

The task is to write the function, find the value, given a specific number, e.g. if user inputs 3, it should return `'foo'`. We can assume that there is no overlapping numbers in the key.

Another e.g., if user inputs 9, it should return `'bar'`.

---

I've tried converting the `x` dict to a list and write the function as follows, but it's suboptimal if the range of values in the keys is extremely huge:

```
from itertools import chain

mappings = None * max(chain(*x))

for k in x:
    for i in range(k[0], k[1]):
        mappings[i] = x[k] 

def myfunc(num):
    return mapping[num]
```

- How else can the `myfunc` function be written?
- Is there a better data structure to keep the `mapping`?

Comment: tuple range is open or close?

Comment: Open for start and close for end. e.g. `(0,4], (4, 9], (9, 10]`

Comment: Can we assume that keys are continuous range?

Comment: Sometimes there are discontinuous range

Comment: If keys are not continuous range then your mapping function is not correct.

Comment: Ah yeah, I have to actually left out that I took the max value and then prepopulate with None before running through the list comprehension.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please let me know if that gives sufficient performance for your dict or not.

Comment: Yes, your answer is nice. The `O(log(n))` approach is way better than brute-force going into each integer in range without the massive footprint of saving an array/list of the mappings.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate through keys and compare the values (rather than creating a mapping). This is a bit more efficient than creating a mapping first, since you could have a key like `(0, 100000)` which will create needless overhead.

Edited answer based on comments from OP

```
x = {(0, 4): 'foo', (4,9): 'bar', (9,10): 'sheep'}

def find_value(k):
    for t1, t2 in x:
        if k > t1 and k <= t2:   # edited based on comments
            return x[(t1, t2)]
    
    # if we end up here, we can't find a match
    # do whatever appropriate, e.g. return None or raise exception
    return None
```

**Note:** <s>it's unclear in your tuple keys if they are inclusive ranges for the input number. E.g. if a user inputs `4`, should they get `'foo'` or `'bar'`? This will affect your comparison in the function described above in my snippet.</s> (see edit above, this should fulfill your requirement).

<s>In this example above, an input of `4` would return `'foo'`, since it would fulfill the condition of being `k >= 0 and k <= 4`, and thus return before continuing the loop.</s>

*Edit: wording and typo fix*

Comment: same approach I'd take, except <= t2 is not the same as range() which is < t2

Comment: @jwal yeah agreed, hoping the OP can clarify the inclusivity of the key values. Another complication is that we are assuming t1 <= t2, which I'm not sure is a safe assumption.

Comment: Hmmm for the range, it's `(0,4], (4, 9], (9, 10]`, `[ ]` refers to inclusive of the number.

Comment: @alvas gotcha, then I would just change the comparison to `k > t1 and k <= t2`. I also see the (10, 10) key was edited to (9, 10) which makes more sense for this type of comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your key in a `numpy` array and use `numpy.searchsorted` to search a query. Since keys are `left open` I have incremented open value of keys by `1` in the array.

Each query is of order `O(log(n))`.

Create an array:

```
A = np.array([[k1+1, k2] for k1, k2 in x])
>>> A
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 5,  9],
       [10, 10]])
```

Function to search query:

```
def myfunc(num):
    ind1 = np.searchsorted(A[:, 0], num, 'right')
    ind2 = np.searchsorted(A[:, 1], num, 'left')
    if ind1 == 0 or ind2 == A.shape[0] or ind1 <= ind2: return None
    return vals[ind2]
```

Prints:

```
>>> myfunc(3)
'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the dictionary comparing to the keys:

```
x = {(0, 4): 'foo', (4, 9): 'bar', (9, 10): 'sheep'}

def find_tuple(dct, num):
    for tup, val in dct.items():
        if tup[0] <= num < tup[1]:
            return val
    return None

print(find_tuple(x, 3))
# foo
print(find_tuple(x, 9))
# sheep
print(find_tuple(x, 11))
# None
```

A better data structure would be a dictionary with just the left boundaries of the intervals (as keys) and the corresponding values. Then you can use `bisect` as the other answers mention.

```
import bisect
import math

x = {
    -math.inf: None,
    0: 'foo',
    4: 'bar',
    9: 'sheep',
    10: None,
}

def find_tuple(dct, num):
    idx = bisect.bisect_right(list(dct.keys()), num)
    return list(dct.values())[idx-1]

print(find_tuple(x, 3))
# foo
print(find_tuple(x, 9))
# sheep
print(find_tuple(x, 11))
# None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using [`pandas.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_tuples.html#pandas-intervalindex-from-tuples) and [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut). Note, I "tweaked" the last key to (10, 11), because I'm using `closed="left"` in my IntervalIndex. You can change this if you want the intervals closed on different sides (or both):

```
import pandas as pd

x = {(0, 4): "foo", (4, 9): "bar", (10, 11): "sheep"}

bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(x, closed="left")
result = pd.cut([3], bins)[0]

print(x[(result.left, result.right)])
```

Prints:

```
foo
```

---

Other solution using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module (assuming the ranges are continuous - so no "gaps"):

```
from bisect import bisect_left

x = {(0, 4): "foo", (4, 9): "bar", (10, 10): "sheep"}

bins, values = [], []
for k in sorted(x):
    bins.append(k[1])  # intervals are closed "right", eg. (0, 4]
    values.append(x[k])

idx = bisect_left(bins, 4)
print(values[idx])
```

Prints:

```
foo
```

Comment: pandas is a hammer the size of the world to crack a very small issue.

Comment: @jwal Yes, that's why I added the `bisect` method as well.